# What is HMM and Viterbi algorithm?

Tags: markov-process, hidden-markov-model, viterbi-algorithm

I have to learn what is HMM and Viterbi alogrithm, I search all pages on Google, but I can't understand what is HMM is and what is Viterbi is, if there is very basic and very simple examples/explanations/tutorial/anything else that will explain me what is this and how to apply Viterbi algorithm on any examples, can you please give a reference link?

Comment: Viterbi Algorithm has been maturely used in digital communications for long, especially used for soft decoding of error-correction code, e.g. convolution code, trellis code, turbo code etc. You can find detailed explanation and examples in a typical textbook on digital communications or error-correction coding (or channel coding).